# AngularJS directive with script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Basically, I have my directive defined **sample.js** as:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            info: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'link-to-sample.html'
    };
});
```

And in my **sample.html** I got (for example):

```
<script>
     $(div).css('height', {{info}}+'px') //THIS DOESN'T WORK
</script>
<div></div>
```

In my, say, **index.html** I would like to pass a numerical value, through the `info=''` tag and use it in the script, running in the **sample.html** file.

```
<my-directive info='100'></my-directive>
```

But using just `{{info}}` in `<script></script>` tags seems not to work.

Would be grateful, if you, guys, help me with this.

---

**P.S.** I know, that I could write a code inside directive, use `compile`, or `template:`, but I would really like to keep in the separate **.html** file.

Comment: i think you can code that `<script>` part in `directive link` function or `directive controller` function

Comment: Why don't you write your script in `link` method of the directive instead of embedding in template?

Comment: How do I use my value passed through `info=` inside the `link` function?

Comment: @HaykHakobyan See my answer below for an example to use `$scope.info` in link function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding script tags in template files to deal with DOM in directives is strongly discouraged. It does not play well with the Angular way of DOM updates, and it does not have access to scope and the surrounding directive. Also, it will break under CSP where inline scripts are disallowed.

The recommended way would be to use the `link` function and remove the script tag in templates.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            info: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'link-to-sample.html',
        link: function (element, $scope, attrs) {
            element.find('div').css('height', $scope.info + 'px');
        },
    };
});
```

You can still keep the separate `sample.html` for your template HTML. You just don't put logic in it. This is better separation of concerns in my opinion.

```
<div></div>
```